# Biber cannot find .bcf control file

Tags: biblatex

```
Процесс запущен: biber.exe "текст"

INFO - This is Biber 2.15
INFO - Logfile is 'ГІГҐГЄГ±ГІ.blg'

ERROR - Cannot find control file 'ГІГҐГЄГ±ГІ.bcf'! - Did latex run successfully on your .tex file before you ran biber?
INFO - ERRORS: 1

Процесс закончился с ошибками
```

My code id here

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{article}
%%% Работа с русским языком
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}   %% загружает пакет многоязыковой вёрстки
\usepackage{fontspec}      %% подготавливает загрузку шрифтов Open Type, True Type и др.

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,mathtools} % AMS
\usepackage{icomma} % "Умная" запятая: $0,2$ --- число, $0, 2$ --- перечисление
%%% Работа с картинками
\usepackage{graphicx}  % Для вставки рисунков
\graphicspath{{images/}{images2/}}  % папки с картинками
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\hypersetup{                % Гиперссылки
    unicode=true,           % русские буквы в раздела PDF
    pdftitle={Заголовок},   % Заголовок
    pdfauthor={Автор},      % Автор
    pdfsubject={Тема},      % Тема
    pdfcreator={Создатель}, % Создатель
    pdfproducer={Производитель}, % Производитель
    pdfkeywords={keyword1} {key2} {key3}, % Ключевые слова
    colorlinks=true,        % false: ссылки в рамках; true: цветные ссылки
    linkcolor=black,          % внутренние ссылки
    citecolor=black,        % на библиографию
    filecolor=magenta,      % на файлы
    urlcolor=blue          % на URL
}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,maxcitenames=1,bibencoding=utf8,backend=biber,sorting=ynt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib1.bib}
\begin{document}
bla bla bla
\printbibliography
\nocite{*}
\end{document}
```

The name of the file was correct, it is located in the same folder with correct  file extension `.bib`

I set `biber` in settings.

Comment: When you ran Latex (or PdfLatex, or whatever you ran), did it run without error? If the document you're compiling doesn't compile cleanly without error, biber/biblatex will not work. They will complain that you don't have a "clean" .tex file to work on. Every time you want to run biber you will have to have a successful compile of your .tex file first (and two runs of it after, to get all the references in order).

Comment: It's much safer to create files with filenames in ASCII.

Comment: @Plergux, yes I run XeLatex first without anу errors, except the one that I mentioned

Comment: is there a .bcf file in the folder of your document?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, it is

Comment: if there is one but biber can not find it, it is quite possible that it is because of your file name. Give your tex file an ascii name and try again.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I renamed both .bib and .tex files an ascii name, but biber cannot find the file

Comment: Did you recompile after the rename? And are you using some option to move output files to some other folder? Are you calling biber from the current directory?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, I did, yeap, directory stays same

Comment: is the blg-file in the same folder?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes

Comment: then I have no other idea why biber can't find the bcf -- normally it either means that biber is looking at the wrong place or the wrong file name.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. `pdftex` compiled correctly, then `biber` gave the same error you received.

In my case the problem was solved by first running `$ pdftex main.tex` followed by `$ biber main` (instead of  `$ biber main.tex`). It no longer requested a missing `.bcf` file---then when I ran `$ pdftex` again everything compiled correctly.

Comment: Contributions are welcome, but this doesn't answer this particular question since the OP's command clearly did not include the `.tex` extension when calling `biber`.